# PCI devices rescan in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, device, pci

Could anyone please tell me how to execute this command in C?

`echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

Should I open the `/sys/bus/pci/rescan` file and `write` 1 into it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes almost, but you need to write th _character_ `'1'`, not the _value_ `1`. Why didn't you try id?

Comment: Yes. This command writes the string 1 and a newline into the file /sys/bus/pci/rescan

Comment: @user253751 yes, writing the string `"1"` is the same as writing the character `'1'`.